# Listing categories controller OpenCart 2 not working

Tags: php, model-view-controller, e-commerce, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm trying to list categories names and images in OpenCart via custom controller and custom template and this code is not working

Controller File catalog\controller\designer\listing.php

```
class ControllerDesignerListing extends Controller {

public function index(){
 $this->document->setTitle("Listign Designers ");

 if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/designer/listing.tpl')) {
     $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/designer/listing.tpl';
 } else {
     $this->template = 'default/template/designer/listing.tpl';
 }


 $this->load->model('catalog/category');

 $this->data['categories'] = array();

 foreach ($this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(array()) as $category) {
     $this->data['categories'][] = array(
         'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
         'name'        => $category['name']
     );
 }


 $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
 $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
 $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
 $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
 $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
 $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');





 // call the "View" to render the output

 $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/designer/listing.tpl', $data));

 }
}
```

and that is the template file

```
      <?php if($categories) { ?>
            <?php foreach  ($categories as $category) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><!--item-->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="img-wrap"><img src="imgs/list-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="flag"><img src="imgs/flag-place.jpg" alt=""></div><a href="#">
                            <h4><?php echo $category['name']; ?></h4></a>
                        <h5>tokyo, japan</h5><a href="#" class="line">FOLLOW</a>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is error showing ?

Comment: Mention the version of opencart you are using. Question shows opencart v2 while description shows below v2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some silly mistake,

Find `$this->data['categories']` in `catalog\controller\designer\listing.php` and replace with `$data['categories']`

This will work .

Whenever, you upgrade opencart files from version `1.5.x.x` to `2.x.x.x`, Always keep this in mind that, this is the major changes which comes in opencart version `2.x.x.x`